# Remove object from JSON file c#

Tags: c#, json

I want to remove object from json after select from combobox and click button. For example i selected Harry Thomas from combobox and after click on the button Person Harry Thomas should be removed. I have problem with remove object from json only. I tried something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Person.Count; ++i)
{
    if (combobox1.Text == result.Person[i].Name + " " + result.Person[i].Surname)
    {
        result.Person[i].Remove();
    }
}
```

Json and classes:

```
{
  "Person": [
    {
      "Speciality": "Archer",
      "Id": 432742,
      "Name": "Charlie",
      "Surname": "Evans",
      "Items": [
        "Bow",
        "Arrow",
      ]
    },
    {
      "Speciality": "Soldier",
      "Id": 432534,
      "Name": "Harry",
      "Surname": "Thomas",
      "Items": [
        "Gun",
        "Knife",
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Monster": [
    {
      "Name": "Papua",
      "Skills": [
        "Jump",
        "SlowWalk",
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Geot",
      "Skills": [
        "Jump",
        "SlowWalk",
      ]
    }
  ]
}

public class Person
{
    public string Speciality { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Monster
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Person> Person { get; set; }
    public List<Monster> Monster { get; set; }
}
```

How to remove object from json file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "i got error" - it would be great to know what kind of error. Please always include that information

Comment: Likely it's because you're changing the collection while iterating over it. While looping over the collection, create a new collection that contains all items that shall be removed. Then loop over that collection and remove each item from the original list.

Comment: ErrorCode is CS1061 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1061)

Comment: The error is because Person does not have a `.Remove()` method. You need to remove the person from a list, so call the remove method at the list, not at the person (`result.Person.Remove(Person[i]);`). But next you'll run into the problem I mentioned before.

Comment: Try `result.Person.RemoveAt(i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var result =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

var name="Harry"; // replace with combobox
var surname="Thomas"; // replace with combobox
result.Person.RemoveAll(i=>  i.Name==name && i.Surname==surname);
```

Answer (score 1):

May try something like

`result.Person = result.Person.Where(item=> combobox1.Text != $"{item.Name} {item.Sorname}").ToList()`

and save the result list in the json file after that